# How to solve non-linear recurrence relation in general?

Tags: recurrence-relations

For linear recurrence, we can use generating function. So is there a general technique to solve non-linear recurrence or it depends on a specific sequence? For example,
$$a_{n+1} = \dfrac{a_n(a_n - 3)}{4}$$ for $a_0 = a$

Comment: There is no method for a general non-linear recurrence.  Indeed, most of them have no (known) closed-form solution at all.

Comment: Your particular example recurrence is conjugate to the iterations of $z^2+c$, where $c=-33/64$ if my computations are correct.  This case has been studied.  Since $c$ is not $0$ and not $-2$, there is no closed form solution (in a certain definite sense).

Comment: Even for linear recurrences, if they aren't constant coefficient, I don't think generating functions always get you a closed form solution.

Comment: Thank you all! Sequences are actually more mysterious than I initially thought.

Answer (score 6):

As already mentioned, **currently for non-linear recurrence relations, there are no known general techniques for obtaining a closed form solution**.

For the very few non-linear recurrences that are actually solvable, the techniques used to solve them are strongly dependent on the specific recurrence that your dealing with.